# Changing default PyGame background from black to white

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to change the default color from black to white.
**not to fill it**.
My current code where I *fill* it:

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()

size = 600, 600

surface = pygame.display.set_mode(size, pygame.RESIZABLE)
surface.fill((255, 255, 255))

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()
    pygame.display.update()
```

It works however it is being shown as black for a second and then it changes itself, and i am looking for a solution where in advance it starts with white background. Thanks in advance

Comment: Just put a pygame.display.update() directly after the screen.fill(). But really, you should fill the background with a color every frame, then draw everything on top of it. It's the most simple way to make a well functioning pygame program.

Comment: I know, even though I put it right after the `fill()` it still doesn't be shown immediately but after a millisecond. i am looking for a solution that will set the color in the initialization of the Surface or something similar

Comment: That’s not possible. Also, just to be clear, in this code you don’t update() directly after fill, you check the event queue first, which takes some time.

Comment: If actually update() directly after fill is still too slow for you, if the black flash for 0.00001 seconds is unacceptable, you can create the window hidden using pygame.HIDDEN and then make it white and then show it by setting mode again with pygame.SHOWN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By @starbuck45 I used the flag `pygame.HIDDEN`.

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()

size = 600, 600
surface = pygame.display.set_mode(size, pygame.RESIZABLE | pygame.HIDDEN)
surface.fill("white")
pygame.display.set_mode(size)

line = pygame.draw.line(surface, "black", (0, 0), (600, 600))


while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()
```

and it worked fine!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help you

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

size = 600, 600

surface = pygame.display.set_mode(size, pygame.RESIZABLE)
surface.fill((255, 255, 255))

while True:
    surface.fill((255, 255, 255))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Yet, it becomes white after a second.